Convergence of the free-space Green's function for the heat equation on the line
Q: The free-space Green’s function for the 1D heat equation

$u_t=u_{x x} \quad t>0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$u(x, 0)=\delta(x-\xi) \quad x, \xi \in \mathbb{R}$ initial condition,

is known to be $G_0(x, t ; \xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 t}} e^{-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{4 t}}$.

Use this to write down an integral formula for the solution to the IBVP $\begin{aligned} u_t & =u_{x x} \quad t>0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R} \\ u(x, 0) & =\frac{1}{1+x^2}\end{aligned}$.  You don’t need to evaluate the integral. What is the long term behaviour (i.e. as $t\to \infty$  ) of the solution?

Solution: We have that the solution will be $u(x, t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{G_0(x, t ; \xi)}{1+\xi^2} d \xi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 t}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{4 t}}}{1+\xi^2} d \xi$. This solution will tend to $0$ as $t\to \infty$ because the integral is bounded and there is a $\frac 1{\sqrt{2t}}$ out front of it. The integral is bounded by
$\begin{aligned}|u(x, t)| & =\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{4 t}}}{1+\xi^2} d \xi\right| \\ & \leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{1+\xi^2}\right| d \xi \\ & =\left.\arctan (\xi)\right|_{\xi=-\infty} ^{\infty}=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi\end{aligned}$.
Since the integral is bounded by $\pi$, we have that $|u(x, t)| \leq \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2} t} \rightarrow 0 \quad$ as $\quad t \rightarrow \infty$.

What result are they using here to justify $u(x,t)\to 0$? Is this just the squeeze theorem? Or is it, say, the Weierstrass M-test?

Yes it is the squeeze theorem. But your equation is wrong there should not be $|u(x,t)| = ...$ since only the integral is being estimated.
